# mTLS fallback to standard TLS

Tags: tls

Is it possible to use both mTLS and regular TLS (as fallback) ?

I would like it to try to auth user with mTLS and fallback to standard login/password when it fail.

Is this a good idea in term of security ? The goal is to simplify life to regular users (mTLS) but without affecting guests (Login/password)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to use both mTLS and regular TLS (as fallback) ?

It is possible that the server requests a client certificate but the client provides none and the server accepts that the client provides none. With nginx this is for example done with [verify_client](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) `optional`.

> Is this a good idea in term of security ?

This depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to use client certificates because it provides better security than passwords, then making it optional is not a good idea. If you want to make it possible to use client certificates for convenient alternative to passwords, then it is usually sufficient if the client certificate is sufficiently protected, i.e. matching you actual (but unknown) security requirements.